# How to get the list of users, while using django.contrib.auth model

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a web based application in which i required to get the list of all registered users in template way. I am using the django.contrib.auth model to manage user database with no groups. I am not able to find out any method in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ which return the list of all user in views.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the the appropriate queryset to your template:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render

def foo(request):
   return render(request,'users.html',{'users': User.objects.all()})
```

Or if this is something you need for all templates, write a [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) and add it there.